# Understanding CNAME in displaydns

Tags: windows-7, dns, ip, cname

On Windows, I do `ipconfig /displaydns`

One record is:

```
 na4.salesforce.com
 ----------------------------------------
 Record Name . . . . . : na4.salesforce.com
 Record Type . . . . . : 5
 Time To Live  . . . . : 8
 Data Length . . . . . : 8
 Section . . . . . . . : Answer
 CNAME Record  . . . . : na4-was.salesforce.com
```

I see no IP for it.

How does Windows resolve the IP for this then?

Note: there is no other entry for na-4-was.salesforce.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CNames or canonical names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) basically let you alias one domain name to another - this makes it simpler if you have *lots* of domain names pointing at the same server - for example, you had seperate domain names for FTP, different domain names for vhosts and so on.In this case na4.salesforce.com points at na4-was.salesforce.com, which then points at somewhere else.

If you run tracert on na4.salesforce.com, it'll look up na4-was.salesforce.com

and you get

```
C:\Users\geek>tracert na4.salesforce.com

Tracing route to na4-was.g.salesforce.com [96.43.150.52]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
```

Which means it simply resolves the ip address for the domain na4-was.g.salesforce.com when you ask for na4-was.g.salesforce.com.

Comment: So it never caches it?  And has to resolve it each time?

Comment: Apparently not. Bizarrely tracert-ing na4-was results in it showing up as a cname for *itself*... which makes no sense at all.

Comment: @dublintech, sorry, why do you think cname records aren't cached?  They are cached like anything else.

Comment: @Zoredache there was no corrresponding entry for the cname record in the cache, in this case.